# Yiic migrate command not working (memory exhausted)

Tags: migration

I'm trying to launch a basic "yiic migrate create BasicMe MyPlugin"
But every time the memory gets exhausted, whatever memory_limit I set (I even tried 8Gb).

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 3279945728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /path/to/craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php on line 266
```

Any idea what's causing it ?

Nicolas

Comment: Sounds like an infinite loop somewhere eating up all the memory. Any stack trace getting logged in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`?

Comment: just in the phperrors.log file  PHP Fatal Error  If I output $name  from __call function, I get "getTranslatedBrowserLanguage"

Comment: Are you on the latest version of Craft? I vaguely recall a bug similar to this that was fixed.

Comment: "You're up to date" it says.

Comment: If you have xDebug setup, you can set a breakpoint on `yiic` and step through and see where the loop is. Otherwise, if it's on a publicly accessible box and you want to throw some SSH credentials to support@buildwithcraft.com, we can look into it.